# Does Job's "covenant with [his] eyes" refer to marriage?

Tags: job, metaphor

Job's final appeal to God includes this assertion of innocence:

> I have covenanted with my eyes
>   Not to gaze on a maiden.—Job 31:1 ([NJPS](http://www.taggedtanakh.org/Chapter/Index/english-Job-31))

The ESV reads this as a rhetorical question:

> ```
> I have made a covenant with my eyes;
>     how then could I gaze at a virgin?
> ```
>
> —Job 31:1 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Job+31/))

In either case, the covenant is between Job and his eyes.  But I would have expected that he would avoid looking at another woman because of his covenant with his wife, i.e. his marriage.  Is this a known metaphor for the marital promises?  Is there some other reading that makes sense of this verse in some other way?

Comment: I ran across this verse while answering the question: [Is it a sin to lust after my wife?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/9230/914)

Comment: @GoneQuiet: What an interesting thought!  I have to say I'm relieved its off the table, however.

Answer (score 3):

The beauty of a young woman comes to us through our eyes, whereby we might be drawn into sin and adultery. Therefore, possibly making a covenant with our eyes is just a poetic way of saying: ‘I have agreed within myself, swore to myself and all the prime members involved, that I will not lustfully gaze after a maiden.’ One might say 'I made a covenant with my hands that I will not shed blood.'